# How to convert date in YYYYMMDD in Hive to unix timestamp

Tags: hive, unix-timestamp, date-conversion

I am trying to convert date in format YYYYMMDD in hive to unix_timestamp but when I do below, I am getting incorrect timestamp.

```
select unix_timestamp(DATE,'YYYYMMDD') from table_name.
```

For `'20180301'` I am getting unix timestamp output as `'1514631600'` which is DECEMBER 30,2017 11:59 pm

Answer (score 1):

The format string should be `yyyyMMdd`.

```
select unix_timestamp(DATE,'yyyyMMdd') from table_name
```